# Can ashkenazim do yichud after the meal

Tags: halacha, wedding

I understand that sifardim do [yihud](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/477338/jewish/Yichud-Room.htm) after the meal and ashkenazim do it before

What is the reason/source ashkinazim do it before?
Can an Ashkenazi person do it after?

Comment: I see the comment at the  link that says Sephardic custom is to perform yichud after the reception. But that's not how it's stated in Ben Ish Chai, Year 1, parshat Shoftim 12. He says bride and groom are escorted to their home to eat a meal together in private immediately after the chuppah and the blessings of Erusin and Nisuin.

Answer (score 2):

[Nitei Gavriel Nisuin 1 - 37:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=220) says the reason Yichud is done immediately after the Chupa is to minimize the Hefsek between the Chupa and Yichud. He mentions that the Sefardim do Yichud after the Seuda and in note 8 that the German Minhag is also to do it after the Seuda since they consider the spreading of the Talis the main part of the Chupa.